# NSPrintOperation spins color wheel several seconds in sandboxed Mac application

Tags: macos, sandbox, nsprintoperation

The following simple call to NSPrintOperation started running very slow and spinning color wheel:

```
NSPrintInfo* printInfo = [NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo];
NSPrintOperation* opeation = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:[self view] printInfo:printInfo];
[opeation runOperation];
```

With following log in console:

```
12:00:37.659430+0300 PrintTest[2196:128061] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 1
12:00:38.660534+0300 PrintTest[2196:128061] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 2
12:00:39.662490+0300 PrintTest[2196:128061] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 3
12:00:40.663736+0300 PrintTest[2196:128061] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect() failed path:/var/run/mDNSResponder Socket:8 Err:-1 Errno:1 Operation not permitted
12:00:40.666875+0300 PrintTest[2196:128061] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 1
12:00:41.667635+0300 PrintTest[2196:128061] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 2
12:00:42.668884+0300 PrintTest[2196:128061] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 3
12:00:43.669116+0300 PrintTest[2196:128061] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect() failed path:/var/run/mDNSResponder Socket:8 Err:-1 Errno:1 Operation not permitted
12:00:43.694588+0300 PrintTest[2196:128061] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 1
12:00:44.694744+0300 PrintTest[2196:128061] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 2
12:00:45.696010+0300 PrintTest[2196:128061] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 3
12:00:46.697261+0300 PrintTest[2196:128061] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect() failed path:/var/run/mDNSResponder Socket:8 Err:-1 Errno:1 Operation not permitted
12:00:46.720609+0300 PrintTest[2196:128061] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 1
12:00:47.720890+0300 PrintTest[2196:128061] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 2
12:00:48.721326+0300 PrintTest[2196:128061] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 3
12:00:49.721529+0300 PrintTest[2196:128061] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect() failed path:/var/run/mDNSResponder Socket:8 Err:-1 Errno:1 Operation not permitted
12:00:49.726589+0300 PrintTest[2196:128061] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 1
12:00:50.727795+0300 PrintTest[2196:128061] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 2
12:00:51.728552+0300 PrintTest[2196:128061] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 3
12:00:52.728778+0300 PrintTest[2196:128061] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect() failed path:/var/run/mDNSResponder Socket:8 Err:-1 Errno:1 Operation not permitted
```

Looks like it started after upgrading to macOS 10.14. It happens only when the sandbox enabled. Printing entitlement is checked. Other sandboxed apps, like Preview and TextEdit seems to be unaffected by this and start printing dialog quickly. Any ideas what can be done to fix this?

Comment: Google found [URLSession DNS failure](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/67792)

Comment: It looks like enabling "Outgoing connections" entitlement removes the issue, but my app should not have this entitlement enabled. Further investigation shows it is CUPS trying connect somewhere but fails. But still other sandbox apps manage to show printing dialog without the spinning wheel and without "Outgoing connections" enabled.